# JSON Array Manipulation using plain JavaScript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I have a JSON Array similar to the structure below.

```
[{
"variable_name": "VAR1_XYZ",
"variable_values": [
            {
                "DomainName": "Env1",
                "Value": "ABC Process 1",
                 (some more key-value pairs)
            },
            {
                "DomainName": "Env2",
                "Value": "DEF Process 1",
                 (some more key-value pairs)
            }],
 },{
"variable_name": "VAR2_UVW",
"variable_values": [
            {
                "DomainName": "Env1",
                "Value": "ABC Process 2",
                 (some more key-value pairs)
            },
            {
                "DomainName": "Env2",
                "Value": "DEF Process 2",
                 (some more key-value pairs)
            }],
 }];
```

I am presenting this data in a table structure with the "**variable_name**" (as rows / cells) value's across multiple "**DomainName**"s (as columns) in an "ng-grid".

I am also having a requirement where the user up on selecting one of the "DomainName"s, the values of the "variable_name"s in the selected Domain would have to be compared against the values with the other Domains and depending on whether there is a match or not, the "ng-grid" table cells need to be color coded as "green" or "red" depending on whether there is a match or not..

I had been looking through plain javascript / json object manipulation and underscore / lodash to understand which is the most efficient way to compare JSON objects with the following structures and I could not come to any conclusion on how to achieve it. I am also a newbie to the lodash / underscore library and may be that is causing this confusion if I am over engineering or if I am taking the right path to solve this problem.

My end goal is to create a generic function that takes the selected domain name and the below array to provide an output array that has a list of true / false boolean values for each "variable_name" / "DomainName" that I can use for coloring the grid.

So, for example, if the user selects DomainName as "Env1", I am looking to get all "variable_name"'s under "Env1" and compare the values of the respective "variable_name"s from other domains and create a result object similar to

```
{Env1 : true, Env2: false, Env3 : true}
```

that I can use for coloring the ng-grid. 
Could you please suggest on what is the approach that should be taken if this has to be done using lodash / underscore? instead of plain javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending which browsers you're supporting, you could do something like this with vanilla ES5:

```
var arr = [{
    "DomainName": "Env1",
    "Value": "ABC Process 1"
}, {
    "DomainName": "Env2",
    "Value": "DEF Process 1"
},
{
    "DomainName": "Env3",
    "Value": "DEF Process 1"
}];

function constructDomainObject(collection, selectedDomains) {
    return collection.reduce(function (memo, domain) {
        var domainName = domain["DomainName"];
        var selected = selectedDomains.some(function (domain) { 
            return domain === domainName 
        });
        memo[domainName] = selected;
        return memo;
    }, {});
}

var data = constructDomainObject(arr, ['Env1', 'Env3']); 
// data = {Env1 : true, Env2: false, Env3 : true}
```

If you're supporting legacy browsers, you could polyfill `reduce` and `some` or use the analogous lodash/underscore methods.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pqnpzte/)

Comment: Thank you for your solution and the fiddle. Though the solution you suggested itself is comparing the domain names, I wanted to compare the values for the "variable_name" for each domain. I should still be able to use the solution suggested with minimal changes. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.